# Figuring out what dp to use

Tags: android, xml, dpi

I designed a few mock ups for my app in 1440 x 2560 frame. When using xml, however, I need to specify the dp to make each element. How can I calculate this size?

For example, I have a button that is 1224 x 220 but it is too big to use "wrap_content" for height. How can I calculate the height I need in dp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dp` units are measurements of physical dimension on the screen, much like `pt`, `mm`, `in`, etc. Specifically `160dp` is one inch. (This is regardless of the pixel density of the screen. So if the physical screen is, say, 320 pixels/inch, then `20dp` is the same as `40px`, because 20/160 of an inch is 40 physical pixels on that screen.)

So size your dimensions in `dp` according to how big you want them to be physically on the screen, using the scale `1dp` = 1/160".